# Annoying vim (un)indent rules

Tags: php, vim, indentation

When editing PHP code (I'm not sure if it's specific to that language) and I create a new line in the middle of comma-separated lists that span multiple lines, the indent rules always unindent the line I'm leaving. [Here's a video of it.](http://toogeneric.com/files/indent2.mov) This happens in arrays, function argument lists, etc.

Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening, or any quicker methods of fixing the error than moving up, re-indenting it, moving down, re-indenting (since it gets cleared when you leave the line), and continuing?

[.vimrc](https://gist.github.com/2806bf9f0fb1424fd375)

Comment: The plot thickens. It seems to only do this unindenting if I hit enter after the first or second item in the list.

Comment: oh hey! i have been looking for your portfolio. i remember seeing it a while back but had lost the link recently. small world :D

Comment: It might help if you show us your ~/.vimrc file and let us know which vim plugins you have installed.

Comment: This problem drives me nuts too

Answer (score 3):

Try `:set indentexpr=""` and see if that helps. See `:help filetype-indent-off` for the section that deals with filetype plugins (which is probably where this indentexpr is coming from).

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything, which seems odd since I have that explicitly enabled in my .vimrc. My understanding is that with that off I'd lose the other "smart" indenting rules, though.

Comment: Tried `:set indentexpr="`, but now I have any auto-indenting at all.

Comment: I find that I work better with just the ":set autoindent" option turned on, rather than something else trying to format my code for me. There is also the "smartindent" option which might be halfway between autoindent and indentexpr.

Answer (score 3):

Your indenting is controlled by the PHP indent script ("filetype indent on" in your .vimrc). I use these options for my PHP indenting, which you put in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`:

```
setlocal autoindent
setlocal cindent
setlocal cinwords=if,else,elseif,do,while,foreach,for,case,default,function,class,interface,abstract,private,public,protected,final
setlocal cinkeys=0{,0},0),!^F,o,O,e

setlocal nosmartindent " don't use smart indent option
```

There's more on this topic on the [vim wiki page for source indenting](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code).

Answer (score 0):

Using "o" in normal mode seems to avoid the issue. Hitting `<esc>o` from insert mode isn't optimal but it's better than the hard way (as described above).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:let g:PHP_default_indenting=1
```

See `:h php-indent`.

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything,

Comment: After you run the command, you have to :setf php again for it to take effect.  Or else put the above in your ~/.vimrc and restart Vim.

Comment: Ah, I see. That doesn't solve this problem, but that's still something I've been wanting to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
set cindkeys=-0#
```

For the # char.  If you are having the same problem as I had with css declarations like

```
width: 100%
```

getting shifted left as well, you can add

```
set cindkeys-=:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `cindent` screws everything up and `smartindent` is usually what you want.

Try putting this in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html,*.css setlocal nocindent smartindent
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to look at indentkeys

eg the default these days is:

indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e,*,<>>,,end,:

Answer (score 0):

Find your php.vim indent file.  e.g. /usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/php.vim

Then look for these lines:

```
elseif lastline =~ '^\s*?>.*<?\%(php\)\=\s*$'
    let lnum = lnum - 1
```

And comment them out by prepending quotation marks, like this:

```
"elseif lastline =~ '^\s*?>.*<?\%(php\)\=\s*$'
"    let lnum = lnum - 1
```

That'll fix it!  No more de-indenting on opening PHP tags `<?`