# What setting in vim counteracts smartindent's refusal to indent # comments in shell scripts?

Tags: shell, vim, auto-indent

I recently started using vim 7 (previously vim 6) and the `smartindent` setting.  For the most part, it works well, though I'm so used to typing a tab after an open brace that it is almost counter-productive.

However, there is one piece of maniacal behaviour.  When editing a shell script, I try to create a comment at the current indent level, but `smartindent` will have nothing to do with it.  It insists that the comment must be at level 0 (no indent).  What's worse, it breaks shift-right ('`>>`' and friends) so that they do not work.  This is outright insubordination, and I'd like to know what's the best way to fix it?

(I'm also not keen on `smartindent`'s ideas about indenting `then` after `if`.)

Preferred solutions will save me manual bashing - I'm being lazy.  One option would be 'turn off `smartindent` when editing shell scripts (leave it on for the rest)'.  Another option would be guidelines on how to find the control script for `smartindent` and what to edit to change the characteristics I don't like.  The final option (which I don't need advice on how to do - just the hint that it is the best, or only, way to restore sanity) is to leave `smartindent` unset.

I saw the vaguely related question on "[(PHP and) annoying vim unindent rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313359/annoying-vim-unindent-rules)"; it doesn't provide me with the direct answer, though maybe the `cindent` and related items mentioned in there are in fact part of the answer.

Comment: Great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191201/indenting-comments-to-match-code-in-vim

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find the indent file, (e.g. /usr/share/vim/vim71/indent/sh.vim on my system)

This line looks like the problem:

```
setlocal indentkeys-=:,0#
```

Perhaps you can fix this in your .vimrc or load a custom indent file manually.

edit: It looks more complicated than I thought, but maybe there is something specifically set in the indenting file that you would need to fix.

2nd edit:  Looks like I was completely wrong,  Check out:

[Restoring indent after typing hash](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restoring_indent_after_typing_hash)

or

[howto-configure-vim-to-not-put-comments-at-the-beginning-of-lines-while-editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354097/howto-configure-vim-to-not-put-comments-at-the-beginning-of-lines-while-editing)

Comment: Good pointers in the right direction. There's a README.txt file which also provides some pointers - notably to ':help indent-expression', which in turn points to 30.3 of the online manual.  But that file is the one that I need to hack, butcher or otherwise modify, countermand or replace.  Thanks!

Comment: Heh...found out that smartindent puts # at the start for C pre-processor directives.  I'm probably going to cancel the shell rules altogether by creating ~/.vim/indent/sh.vim containing ':let b:did_indent = 1'.  I'll chase the links you added with the second edit, too.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after exploring some options, including using '`:set cindent`' instead of '`:set smartindent`', I've ended up reverting to just using '`:set autoindent`'.  There probably are ways to make this stuff work exactly as I want it to, but it is messy enough and fiddly enough that I can't be bothered.  I've worked fine with `autoindent` for the previous 20-odd years, and the benefits from the extra bells and whistles provided by `smartindent` are outweighed by the what I regard as its misbehaviour.

Thank you, Juan, for your assistance.  Believe it or not, it did help - quite a lot.

I also discovered a couple of other neat commands, though, while following up on this:

```
>i}
>a}
```

These right-shift the block of code you are in.  The '`i`' version indents the body and not the closing braces (my preferred style), and the '`a`' version indents the closing braces to (the version that is required at work).

Also, you can apply qualifiers to '`%`' in commands executed at the shell:

```
:make %:r.o
```

This would run make on the 'root' of the current file name (that's '`%:r`') followed by '`.o`'.  Or, in other words, if I'm editing `somefile.c`, this executes `make somefile.o`.

Comment: Glad to help.  Thanks for the tip about shifting blocks.  I shift blocks all the time, but was visually selecting text and using the right shift (>>) operator.

Comment: I used to use '>%' on the line with the open or close brace to shift everything. I'd also use '>%<<%<<' to shift the body of a block right and then unindent the two braces. But those new commands seem to work in the middle of a block, which is nice.

Answer (score 3):

Add the line below in your .vimrc

filetype indent on

(it will set the right indent mode depending on the filetype)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue for a long time, until I realized that autoindent and smartindent are both unnecessary if "filetype indent on" is set in your vimrc - 'filetype indent on' uses the indent/sh.vim (or whatever language) file in your vim directory to figure out the indentation rules, and autoindent and smartindent both can interfere with it.

I haven't tested this with sh, but perl suddenly started behaving properly when I switched.

Sidenote: Juan's redirect, "Restoring indent after typing hash", is not a good solution - while it does correct the problem in one situation (typing code in), it doesn't change how the editor thinks it *should* be indented, so a re-indent (visual =, or normal ==) will shove it back to the left.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer suggesting:

:inoremap # X^H#

is excellent.  It is the answer suggested by the VIM documentation at ":help smartindent".  Note that ^H is entered using CTRL-V CTRL-H.  The relevant section from the documentation is below.

```
    When typing '#' as the first character in a new line, the indent for
    that line is removed, the '#' is put in the first column.  The indent
    is restored for the next line.  If you don't want this, use this
    mapping: ":inoremap # X^H#", where ^H is entered with CTRL-V CTRL-H.
    When using the ">>" command, lines starting with '#' are not shifted
    right.
```

Comment: thank you for posting this! With all the special characters it is not the easiest tip to search for..

Answer (score 1):

I have the following lines in my .vimrc and I don't observe the problem.

```
set smartindent
inoremap # X^H#
```

I used to have *set autoindent* after these two lines but it seems that it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is *very* annoying. smartindent is really only for C like languages.
See how I enable the appropriate indenting based on language at:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/settings/.vimrc