# Vim can't indent (>>) lines, if first character starts with a #

Tags: vim, macvim

Vim can't indent (>>) lines, if line starts with a #.

The problem is evident in all file types. I tried disabling smartindent in vimrc. But still no go.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/385327/513198) of previous question but in any case you should find an answer there

[Restoring indent after typing hash](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restoring_indent_after_typing_hash)